# Can I use copyField with patterns?

Tags: solr, schema

I have several groupFields in my index.
Can I write copyField pattern such that

```
 <copyField source="*_attr_group" dest="important_text"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this has been supported since Solr v 1.1.0 see [JIRA issue SOLR-21](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-21) for more details.